# Is there a way to include tag-like text in XML?

Tags: xml, tags, xsd-validation, subtitle

I have an XML document with ttml (subtitles) format.
One of the lines suppose to include a text that is interpreted as a start tag:
<tt:span>**<some_text>**</tt:span>
where "<some_text>" is the text that should be displayed on the screen when the subtitles are applied, including the < and >.
Because it is interpreted as a start tag, the document doesn't pass xsd validation.

I tried the escape the < (>) with &lt; (&gt;), but it didn't work.

Is there a way to make the document pass the validation, and keep "<some_text>" as text?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a CDATA section. Anything inside of it would be treated as a text.

**XML**

```
<root>
    <city><![CDATA[anything you want is here]]></city>
</root>
```

Comment: OK, now it passes the validation, so it appears as <![CDATA[<some_text>]]> in the document, but when I display the subtitles, I only see "]]>", which means that it took the ">" of the text inside the CDATA and used it as a closing angle bracket. This is not the outcome I was hoping for. Is there a way to fix this? (is it a different issue that should be addressed in a question?)

Comment: @NettaSteinberg, I sent you a LinkedIn invite.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried the escape the < (>) with < (>), but it didn't work.

`&lt;` and `&gt;` is the correct way to escape `<` and `>`.

The following TTML document is [valid](https://apps.sandflow.com/imscV/):

```
<tt xml:lang="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml">
  <body>
    <div>
      <p>&lt;Lorem ipsum&gt;</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</tt>
```

and [renders](http://sandflow.com/imsc1_1/index.html) as expected.